# How to offload tasks using falcon in python?

Tags: python, uwsgi, falcon

I'm using falcon as my web server back-end, and wrap it with uwsgi, very much similar to [this example](http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user/quickstart.html#more-features). I want to offload a task, [like uwsgi allows](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/OffloadSubsystem.html). I want a POST request to produce a 202, and to start a thread that takes care of the request.

In uwsgi it's done with `offload-threads = X`. Does anyone know how to achieve this with falcon?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Falcon doesn't have any native way to accomplish this. But you may try to either:
- Put your task into a [Celery task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)
- Or let the webserver handle that for you. E.g. With gunicorn you can create have workers (based on greenlet, tornado, and other concurrency implementation). You can you do something like:

```
gunicorn --workers=4 myapp:app --worker-class='gevent'
```

Check this  thread for some additional info:
[Python falcon and async operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297072/python-falcon-and-async-operations)